# Dynamically building a button with an onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically building a button in JavaScript, this will include an onClick event. The onClick event needs to focus a field which is stored in a variable.

I couldn't find a way of using the field variable itself, so instead decided to try using the field.selector property from the JQuery object, this WILL contain " ".

Here is a code snippet of the construction as it stands.

```
InvalidField.prototype.getMessageStructure = function(){
    var structure = '<div class="invalidMessage"><span>' + this._message + '</span>
        <button class="inputButton" 
            Value="Go To Field" 
            onclick=\'goToFieldFromAlert($(\'' + this._field.selector + '\'))\'
        />
    </div>';
    return structure;
};
```

This is outputting:

```
<button class="inputButton" 
    value="Go To Field" 
    onclick="goToFieldFromAlert($(" input[name="applicant.email" ]'))'="">
</button>
```

As you can see, the quotations will not be out put correctly and so break on click.

Can anyone foresee a better way of performing this function, or correcting the quotations? I see from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050953/javascript-build-dynamic-string) that the DOM doesn't respect the quotations which is what is currently causing me the issue.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Simply escape the quotes?

Comment: In jQuery, as a general guideline, attach event handlers to the elements. Do not use `onclick` attributes. Also double-quotes are standard for attributes `onclick="..."` anyway :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie The problem with using double-quotes as standard on the onclick event is that the jquery.selector has quotations in it which I can't escape unless I use .replace, which then just starts to get even more messy.

Comment: @Nit I can't escape the quotes that are contained inside of the _field.selector property. This issue, combined with the escaped single quotations being converted in to double quotations by the DOM, causes the quotations to be ended mid line.

Comment: @David Moores: As I also said... you should not use `onclick` at all.  Attach a handler via jQuery and all your problems will be avoided. The field selector can be injected as a `data-field` attribute and picked up by the handler (this is the sort of thing unobtrusive Ajax does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, avoid using `onclick` at all. jQuery event handlers are far more flexible (and support multiple event handlers).

1) Inject the fieldname (only, not the jQuery selector) into a data- attribute:

```
InvalidField.prototype.getMessageStructure = function(){
    var structure = '<div class="invalidMessage"><span>' + this._message + '</span>
        <button class="inputButton" 
            value="Go To Field" data-field="' + this._field.name + '"/>
    </div>';
    return structure;
};
```

2) Use a delegated event handler to get all clicks on inputButtons with less overhead. Extract the field name and do the jQuery where it belongs:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.inputButton', function() {
       var $button = $(this);
       var field = $button.data('field');
       goToFieldFromAlert('input[name="' + field + '"]');
  });
```

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't know I could attach information on to the button itself. That was the prohibiting factor from having a separate on click event. Learnt something very useful there!

Comment: @David Moores: `data-` attributes go hand-in-hand with jQuery plugins and are more flexible than the usual *options* object passed to most plugins so I highly recommend using `data-` attributes to get extra data into the page for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You should create element using jQuery. This is much cleaner and error free approach

*An example with your code*

```
InvalidField.prototype.getMessageStructure = function(){
    var structure = 
        $('<div></div>').append(
            $('<span></span>').text(this._message)
        );
    structure.append(
        $('<button></button>')
            .addClass('inputButton')
            .text("Go To Field")
            .click(function(){
                goToFieldFromAlert($(this._field.selector));
            })
    );          
    return structure;
};
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm not very familiar with JQuery outside of selectors, so I'll read up on this approach. The code isn't working for me, but I feel this is due to matters outside of the extracts I have provided.

Comment: Thank you Satpal, I ended up using an amalgamation of yours and TrueBlue's responses. It feels much cleaner now.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will dynamically add buttons:

```
hello.forEach( function(result) {
  var card = document.createElement("input");
  card.type = "button";
  card.onclick = function() {
     newcard( result );
  }
  card.value = value; // some value
  card.style.backgroundColor="#5ABC7B";
  document.body.appendChild(card);
});
```